# How to duplicate a linked object?

Tags: linked-data

I thought “Duplicate Link” is what I’m looking for, but if I use duplicate link, the new poly will not have a link icon on it.
Is there any other wayt to duplicate a linked object?

[image]

＝　＝　＝

Thank you for all replies.

What I want to try is linking two same object into the .blend I'm working in, I tried alt+D, but still only the first linked file changed.
[image]

＝　＝　＝

@stphnl329 Do you reload B and C or only the B object?
This is how I reload B object, I'm not sure if it is right...?
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate an object or a file? It seems that you're trying to duplicate an object rather than a file.

Comment: @stphnl329 Yes, sorry, bad English ability. I mean duplicate an object. It's impossible to link a .blend file directly, isn't it?

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to duplicate the object, but still let it be linked to the original file?

Comment: I believe you'll have to link all the objects one by one to the other file. However, (to my knowledge) Blender does not show when you've linked objects within a file. Those link icons will only appear if the object has been directly linked to that in another file. That first plane is linked to the last one (but since its the same file, it doesn't show an icon), meaning that if the plane in the other file is changed, the Plane on the bottom there will be changed, causing the middle plane to be changed since it is linked to the last one.

Comment: It definitely sounds like a bit of a mess...but Alt+D will work for you in this situation.

Comment: Just to rephrase, you have objects A,B, and C. A is in another file. B is linked to A, and you want to create object C from B that is also linked to A. Using Alt+D on object B will create C linked to B. Blender will not show you that link, but if you change A, you will have changed B. But since C is linked to B, C will also change.

Comment: @stphnl329 Umm... let me try again. If I have one object in A.blend. I want to link it into B.blend, can I make 2 or 3 or even more in B.blend, instead of only one?

Comment: And the pictures I added above means... if C is linked to B, B is linked to A, C should also change after I make some change on A, isn't it? But it didn't, only B changed.

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked for me. Make sure you have saved the changes to file A, and reload the second file.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can see the link icon in the object data properties.